# Kotlin media player notification buttons do not take any action

Tags: android, kotlin, android-music-player, media-buttons

I'm trying to develop a music playback application in kotlin as a foreground service with android studio but I'm having some problems with the notification buttons: I can't assign them a function on music playback.

Here's how I did it:

I created a foreground service with a `MediaSessionCompat` and a `MediaPlayer`.
I created a `MediaSessionCompat.Callback` object to override some methods as follow :

```
private val callback = object: MediaSessionCompat.Callback() {
        override fun onPlay() {
            super.onPlay()
            if( !successfullyRetrievedAudioFocus() ) {
                return;
            }
            Log.i("onPlay : ","ça marche !")
            isPlaying = true
            mediaSession.setActive(true);
            setMediaPlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING)
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }

        override fun onPause() {
            super.onPause()
            Log.i("onPause : ","ça marche !")
            if(isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.pause()
                isPlaying = false
                setMediaPlaybackState(PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PAUSED);
            }
        }
...}
```

Using the following helper method to set the state :

```
private fun setMediaPlaybackState(state: Int) {
        if (state == PlaybackStateCompat.STATE_PLAYING) {
            stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE)
        } else {
            stateBuilder.setActions(PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY)
        }
        stateBuilder.setState(state, PlaybackStateCompat.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0f)
        mediaSession.setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())
    }
```

Then in the `onCreate()` service method, I initialized the `mediaSessionCompat` object :

```
stateBuilder = PlaybackStateCompat.Builder()
            .setActions(
                PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PAUSE
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP
                        or PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SEEK_TO)

val mediaButtonReceiver = ComponentName(applicationContext, MyMediaButtonReceiver::class.java)
mediaSession = MediaSessionCompat(applicationContext, "Tag", mediaButtonReceiver, null)

mediaSession.apply {
       setCallback(callback)
       setPlaybackState(stateBuilder.build())
       setFlags(
           MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS or
                   MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS
       )
       setActive(true)
}
```

I also created a `MediaButtonReceiver` class to override the `onReceive` method as needed :

```
class MyMediaButtonReceiver : MediaButtonReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(cxt: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val event: KeyEvent?
        val action: Int

        //Log.i("uno", "intent.getAction(): " + intent.action)
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON != intent.action) {
            return
        }

        event = intent.getParcelableExtra<Parcelable>(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT) as KeyEvent

        //Log.i("uno", "EXTRA_KEY_EVENT: " + event)
        if (event == null) {
            return
        }


        //Log.i("uno", "event.KeyCode: " + event.keyCode)
        when(event.keyCode){
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE -> Log.i("keycode", "KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE")
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY -> Log.i("keycode", "KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY")
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE -> Log.i("keycode", "KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE")
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS -> Log.i("keycode", "KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS")
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT -> Log.i("keycode", "KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT")
        }
    }

}
```

And I have referenced it in the manifest :

```
        <receiver android:name=".MyMediaButtonReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".MyMediaPlayerService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I created a good notification with buttons :

```
            addAction(
                NotificationCompat.Action(
                    if(isPlaying) R.drawable.ic_play else R.drawable.ic_pause,
                    "Pause",
                    MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(
                        applicationContext,
                        PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE
                    )
                )
            )
...
setStyle(androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                .setMediaSession(mediaSession.sessionToken)
                .setShowActionsInCompactView(1)
)
```

To finish, in the `onStartCommand()`, I added this command :

MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(mediaSession, intent)

Now here are the results I get: when the service starts, the notification appears correctly as a music notification, with the buttons and the playback information. When pressing the pause button for example, I get the corresponding log defined in the `MyMediaButtonReceiver` class but nothing happens to the music playback.
However, the `MediaButtonReceiver` also takes the information from the headphone buttons for example, and when I plug a headphone into my phone, the next song and previous song buttons work.

Can you help me to identify my error please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).